# Relational database, photos, votes and warnings

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

I'm designing a relational database, but I'm not too much experienced, so I'd like to ask a suggestion about the relational tables with photos.

I thought to use a `table` to store `photos`, and one or more tables for user data and subject links, so the photos can be linked to different subjects, for example to `houses`, or `trees`, in this case I could have this structure:

```
table_houses
- house_id
- house_name
- house_architect_name, house_..., etc.

table_trees
- tree_id
- tree_name
- tree_plant_type, tree_..., etc.

table_photos
- photo_id
- photo_filename
- photo_date
- photo_user_id

table_rel_houses
- rel_id
- rel_house_id
- rel_photo_id
- rel_user_id
- rel_vote_id
- rel_warn_id

table_rel_trees
- rel_id
- rel_tree_id
- rel_photo_id
- rel_user_id
- rel_vote_id
- rel_warn_id

table_warns, table_votes, etc.
```

In this case, the relational tables should have the same structure, because the work in the same way, but point to a different subject (house or tree type).

Could the structure of the data be correct or should I scompose much more the relational table in a `table_rel_votes` and `table_rel_warns`?

I'll need classical pages with a bigger photo and the thumbnails to navigate others, I must consider that the structure could store many millions of photos rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to consider modelling your database as follows:

```
table_photos
- photo_id
- photo_filename
- photo_date
- photo_user_id
- vote_id
- warn_id
- type
- detail_id

table_houses
- id
- name
- style

table_trees
- id
- name
- species
```

In this case, you can define your photo subject in the `type` field, such as 1 = Tree, 2 = House, etc. You will still be able to have many photos for the same subject without data duplication, but you will avoid having to build the `table_rel_xxx` tables with the repeated column schema. I prefer to avoid that when possible.

In this case, you would be able to build queries such as:

```
SELECT 
    table_trees.name
FROM
    table_photos
INNER JOIN
    table_trees ON 
    (table_trees.id = table_photos.detail_id AND table_photos.type = 1);
```

Or else simply query all the photos without "late binding" with the specific type:

```
SELECT 
    photo_filename
FROM
    table_photos;
```

You may be interested in checking out the following articles related to this database model:

- [Stack Overflow - Polymorphism in SQL database tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561576/polymorphism-in-sql-database-tables)
- [Data, Design, and SQL Server - Disjoint subtyping in SQL](http://blogs.msdn.com/dfurman/archive/2009/08/31/disjoint-subtyping-in-sql.aspx)

These are techniques that attempt to implement *polymorphic associations* in a relational database, even though there is no support for this in SQL at a language level.

One drawback of this method is that it makes foreign key constraints quite tricky to define. You would need a foreign key constraint to have a guarantee that if `table_photos` is making a reference to a row in table_trees, that row really exists. A solution for the foreign keys problem is described, with a very good example, in the following EMC article:

- [Distributed Keys and Disjoint Subtypes](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/davidportas/archive/2007/01/08/Distributed-Keys-and-Disjoint-Subtypes.aspx)