# How to guarantee uniqueness when N tables have 1:1 relationship with a common table?

Tags: database, database-design, constraints

Lets suppose I have a scenario with the following model: An `Animal` table which represents any animal, a `Dog` table and a `Bird` table, each one with a 1:1 relationship with the `Animal` table.

Animal

```
    INTEGER id (PK)
    STRING name
```

Bird

```
    INTEGER id (PK FK referencing `Animal.id`)
```

Dog

```
    INTEGER id (PK FK referencing `Animal.id`)
```

*(I'm giving only the keys just to be clear)*

How can I guarantee that a given row in the `Animal` table will have **JUST** one referenced row in either the `Dog` or the `Bird` table? The model itself allows it...

An animal can't be a `Dog` and a `Bird` at the same time (*not in mythology but that's not the case :P*)

It would be better if this could be done just by playing with the model, without triggers...

Any tip would be appreciated :)

Comment: Google disjoint subtype and you'll find loads of info on this problem. The general concensus seems to be that @TonyAndrews answer is the best way..

Comment: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/davidportas/archive/2007/01/08/Distributed-Keys-and-Disjoint-Subtypes.aspx

Comment: great link! it exposes the approach that @TonyAndrews gave us.

Comment: I just noticed that this is pretty much a duplicate of another question with [pretty much the same accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561576/polymorphism-in-sql-database-tables/562030#562030) as @Tony Andrews'.

Comment: Sorry, i haven't found it before asking, we must agree the title doesn't helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be what @Pranay meant, but the answer was incomplete.  Add a column TYPE to all tables and then constrain it like this:

```
create table Animal (id integer, 
                     type string,
                     name string,
                     primary key (id),
                     unique (id, type)
                    );

create table Bird (id integer,
                   type string default 'BIRD' check (type='BIRD'),
                   primary key (id),
                   foreign key (id, type) references Animal (id, type)
                  );

create table Dog (id integer,
                  type string default 'DOG' check (type='DOG'),
                  primary key (id),
                  foreign key (id, type) references Animal (id, type)
                 );
```

See [David Portas's blog](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/davidportas/archive/2007/01/08/Distributed-Keys-and-Disjoint-Subtypes.aspx) fora good explanation of this.

Comment: I think the OP wanted a solution that didn't have these kinds type checking constraints? Also, the type field on the Bird and Dog tables are effectively duplicate / unnecessary data (although it could be considered just part of the foreign key). It should work though :)

Comment: Oh, also, that is database engine specific. That will work for SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access but not MySQL, which has slightly different syntax. You could use the general CONSTRAINT syntax though, which would achieve the same thing and be engine independent. Here's some [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp).

Comment: @spycho: OP said they didn't want triggers, just "playing with the model" - and that's what I have done.  Agree the syntax may be different on different DBMSs, but presume OP can adjust.

Comment: That's one good solution :) even thought it's weird to have a fixed type attribute on the Bird's and Dog's table..

Comment: Yes, if it was me I would either go with this solution or have a trigger when inserting to bird or dog that checks that the animal id doesn't already exist in another animal table. With Tony's constraint solution, the tables look a little odd, you have composite primary keys (not necessarily a bad thing) and it doesn't look as though it is in normal form (not always a problem). With the trigger solution, the triggers have the potential to get bigger and bigger as you add more types of animal. You could probably code that sensibly though, so that it doesn't take much effort to add another type.

Comment: Even though the model becomes a little odd, it's the best approach so far without triggers.

Comment: And to power up the solution, the 'type' attributes could be part of an Enum (depending on the DBMS, at least in postgres AFAIK).

Comment: With a default value in the subtype tables (see amended answer) you don't actually have to specify the TYPE column when inserting.

Comment: Yup, with default values plus enums consistency, it appears to be the best way to deal with it..

Comment: Of course, this doesn't prevent setting up an Animal with no row in any of the subtype tables.  That is a bit more tricky...

Comment: For that, you need a trigger :)

Comment: Tecnically, we need to create the Animal row first anyways, and at that time no referenced row exists in any subtype tables.

Comment: One other thing to note: the cited article state that this solution conforms to 5th normal form. I would say it violates 3NF. Each attribute not part of the primary key must non-transitively depend upon the whole of the PK. If your Animals have an age attribute, the age must depend upon the whole of the PK. I would say that age depends upon the id of the animal but not its type. You could fix this by removing type from the PK. Type isn't something that uniquely identifies the animal. It's probably not a problem in this instance though.

Comment: @Everton, regarding creating the Animal row first: If you insert both Animal and animal sub-type rows as part of a transaction, you can do them in any order you feel like if you are just using constraints. Constraints are turned off during transactions and turned on again afterwards. This is so that you can force an Animal to only be inserted if a Dog for that Animal exists whilst also forcing a Dog to only be inserted if an Animal for that Dog exists. If, when you come to end the transaction, constraints are violated, it will throw an error and roll-back.

Comment: For a different, easier example, it is feasible to only insert a customer row if they have bought something (i.e. have at least one row in the sale table), and to only insert a sale row if there is a customer to reference for that sale.

Comment: Actually, regarding normal form... If the ID of an animal does not uniquely identify it, I think it's OK: Bird number 5 is aged 3. Dog number 5 is aged 7. The age is dependant on not just the id of the animal, but the type of the animal as well.

Comment: @Spycho, you are right about violating 3NF. The Type attribute in Bird and Dog actually violates 2NF. It's a great shame that SQL's lame support for referential integrity forces the use of hacks like this.

Comment: So it does... Good point. I knew something smelled bad. Still, it's not always the wrong thing to do to break normal form. It depends on the circumstance (e.g. performance critical queries).

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it's a matter of Tradeoff's

Comment: The principle is good, but just to nitpick: 1. I don't see what "unique (id, type)" does for you. If id is the primary key, it must be unique by itself. Saying that id+tye is unique is a tautology. 2. You could solve the denormalization problem by saying that the primary key is type+id rather than just id, and make no promises about the uniqueness of id alone. That would make joins require two fields instead of one, and I really can't think of any advantage other than allowing you to check a box and say "yup, it's normalized". But it would let you do that if you're pedantic.

Comment: @Jay, in Tony's original solution, that's how it was (see edits). It still violates normal form that way though. But yeah, it arguably doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, it was dportas who restored (ID) as PK, not me.  But @Jay, re 'I don't see what "unique (id, type)" does for you' the answer is: it makes it possible to ensure that an Animal is not both a Dog and a Bird - which is what the OP was asking.  Yes it's a tautology, but a useful one.

Comment: @Tony: Maybe I'm missing something, but if id is unique -- as it must be if it's the primary key -- then declaring that id+type is unique creates no additional restriction. You cannot have a 17,Bird and a 17,Dog because you can only have one record 17. The foreign keys in the "subclasses" combined with the presence of the type fields prevent two different subclasses from pointing to the same record.

Comment: You are missing that without the (ID,Type) foreign key you could insert Animal(ID=17), Dog(ID=17) and Bird(ID=17), thus creating an Animal that has both a Bird and a Dog subtype - exactly what the OP asked how to prevent.

Comment: This technique has a name:  Shared Primary Key.

Answer (score 1):

In you databayse you can add one more column in you table like AnimalType

```
AnimalTable 
   Id
   AnimalType -- 1 = dog, 2= bird, 3= other
```

Comment: What if the Bird table stores something like wing span? You shouldn't put that in the Animal table (because not all animals have wings). Hence the need for another table.

Comment: Yeah, with this I could create Views for each type of animal, but my goal is to store separate data for each type of animal, without flooding the model.

Comment: If you do that, then you are shifting your problem to enforcing consistency between the value in an AnimalType column, and the particular table that the AnimalID appears in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't *think* that this can be done without [triggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) / [constraints](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp) whilst keeping the tables separate.

Comment: I'm sincerely thinking the same so far :(

Comment: Triggers aren't the end of the world though... They exist for precisely this kind of thing.

Answer (score -2):

I feel that the database design here is wrong. The reason I say that is it seems that for every new animal you have to create new table. In general you want to create a database in the way so that every time you need to add data the schema does not change.

Here is one way to do it:
**Table animals**
animal_id PK
name

**Table animailProperties**
property_id PK
name

**Table animalDecription**
animail_id FK
property_id FK
property_data

Example:

**Table animals**
1 DOG
2 Cat
3 Bird

**Table animailProperties**
1 legs
2 wings
3 fly

**Table animalDecription**
1 1 4 (dog legs 4)
1 2 0 (dog wings 0)
1 3 0 (dog fly no)
2 1 4 (cat legs 4)
2 2 0 (cat wings 0)
2 3 0 (cat fly no)
3 1 2 (bird legs 2)
3 2 2 (bird wings 2)
3 3 1 (bird fly yes)

Something along these lines. So you can create any type of properties for every possible animal.
Every time you need to create a new animal, you just assign correct properties to it.

I hope it helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011956/multiple-fixed-tables-vs-flexible-abstract-tables<br>What about this post?