# How to model user's activity in database?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I want to record some type of user's activity, 
i.e, a user login, or publish a new post.

I come up two way to do this in database:

1, create an Activity table

```
activity_type [enum of activity type]
meta_data
```

use meta_data to store the info of specified activity.
But I can only store meta_data as string for objects, and seems 
not efficient to do query with filter.

2, create a table for every type of activity

```
# loginActivity
time
ip
# publishActivity
post_id
user_id
```

The problem of this way is if there is a new type of activity I want 
to record, a new table should be created.

Which way is more suitable for this situation? Or is there a better
way to do this?

Comment: Google re stackoverflow sql/database subtypes/inheritance/polymorphism. Also multiple tables vs one table, and pros & cons of EAV. These are all faqs. PS What is wrong with having tables? That's what  databases consist of & what DBMSs manage.

Comment: @philipxy I found a good example at  [polymorphism-in-sql-database-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561576/polymorphism-in-sql-database-tables). BTW, having tables is not wrong but when the solution is to create too many tables it made me doubt is it a stupid solution as I do not have much experience in database design :(